# How to state it was long time since you used something

Tags: traducción

For example, I wish to state that it's been a long time since I used or studied Spanish, would that be?

> Hace muchos años que lo usé

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translation is correct however "usé" sounds like if you were talking about an object.

To better express the idea about the *knowledge* of a language I think you should use verbs like "estudiar" "hablar" o "practicar" i.e.

> Hace muchos años que lo **estudié**, pero no lo he **hablado** en mucho tiempo. (It's been years since I studied it, but I've not spoken it in a while)
>
> Hace mucho tiempo que no lo **hablo/practico**. (It's been a long time since I spoke it)

You can also change the order of the sentence :

> Lo estudié/hablé hace mucho tiempo
>
> Estudié español hace mucho tiempo.

Comment: I edited your answer because *I've not* is not English.

Comment: The usage I've not is perfectly OK although I was taught as a child only to use it in direct speech. I would query the other sentence though: 'It's been a long time since I spoke it' sounds much better to my ears (as a native of the UK).

Comment: @Ustanak Since I'm not a native english speaker I just made a search and _"I've not"_  is ok. Thanks anyway for making me doubt. That is how we learn

Comment: @DGaleano I asked to my native teacher, don't worry.

Comment: @mdewey I agree with your comment. It sounds a lot better. Anyway it would be nice to know if _"It's been a long time since I don't speak/practice it"_ is wrong.

Comment: @DGaleano I would say it is wrong